# How can I break <li> elements vertically

Tags: css, layout, html-lists

I have a list of `<li>` elements where the  `<ul>` has a fixed size of 150px (height) and 400px (width)

### How are you today

[image: Original]

### How I would like to stay:

[image: Objetive]

NOTE: This list is dynamic!

**Thank you all for your help**

Comment: Do you mean horizontally? that's how your arrow is pointing.

Comment: yeah, he wants to split the long list into 4 columns it seems.

Comment: Do you have to use a UL or is a table an option?

Comment: You don't need tables to do this.

Comment: I would use `ul`, so it's easy to manipulate via javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

`LI`s go vertically or horizontally, they do not wrap to new coloumns.

If you want lists as illustrated you need to use multiple `UL`s and float them.

If your LIs in on big long list, you can write some JavaScript that will break them down into multiple ULs. CSS cannot do this by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe an answer to an old post. But if you want your list items to be dynamic and in 4 columns, you could use this in the CSS.

```
div {
    -webkit-columns: 100px 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 100px 4; /* Firefox */
    columns: 100px 4;
}
```

Wrap a div around the `<ul>` and than use this css.

Working **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ysm7jmu4/)**

Comment: I'm surprised this is not selected as the correct answer.. and a totally wrong one is :s

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multiple containers and distribute the elements between them. CSS doesn't currently support columnar layouts such as what you're trying.

Anyway, if the content is generated server-side, you can separate into columns there. Otherwise you can do it client-side with JavaScript. If you don't mind jQuery, something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) can do all the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

sorry to disappoint but you'll need to break the list into three,

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
 ...
</ul>

<ul>
 <li></li>
 ...
</ul>

<ul>
 <li></li>
 ...
</ul>
```

set a width for the ul elements and let them float

```
ul {
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
}
```

a following element should have clear: left;

Answer (score 0):

you may use the css display property.

```
ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer, not just post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply float them...

```
li { float: left; width: 200px; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/LY6NW/)

or use inline-block....

```
li { display: inline-block; width: 200px; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/LY6NW/1/)

These do result in list items being displayed horizontally rather than vertically. 
If you want list items to remain listed vertically, then you need to use mutiple containers (`ul`) for each list.

Answer (score 0):

When you think about your problem a bit creative then there is a relative easy solution.

You must just decide how much li's you have at max in one column. When you get your data dynamically, then you can directly create the ul's dynamically.
It can be achieved on server side and also on client side without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the dimensions in pixels of the UL and LI elements, you can position the LIs easily, at least theoretically. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>example<title>
<style type="text/css">
ul { border : 2px solid blue ; height : 200px }
li { height : 25px; }
li:nth-child(9),
li:nth-child(17),
li:nth-child(25), 
li:nth-child(33) {
  margin-top : -200px
}
li:nth-child(8)  ~ li { margin-left : 150px }
li:nth-child(16) ~ li { margin-left : 300px }
li:nth-child(24) ~ li { margin-left : 450px }
li:nth-child(32) ~ li { margin-left : 600px }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>LI number 1</li>
  <li>LI number 2</li>
  ...
  <li>LI number 36</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The UL block will only be as high as the latest column, so you need to explicitly set its height.